# I don't understand the difference between these two lines of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written this code in two different ways. Only the second one works, but I don't get why.

1:

```
buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400).grid()
buttons.columnconfigure(0)
```

2:

```
buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400)
buttons.grid()
buttons.columnconfigure(0)
```

Comment: Because you have to create an object based on class Frame first and run method grid() on that object, not on class Frame? I have no idea what you code is supposed to do by the way, just guessing. What does your error message say?

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columnconfigure'

Comment: @KatiaPunter very accurate guess I believe

Comment: Probably because .grid() does not return any value

Comment: The problem you have here is that `buttons` on the first snippet is the return of the `grid` function, while in the second the return of the `Frame` constructor is the `Frame` object. Btw if `grid` would return `self` then you would be allowed to do it.

Comment: Isn't: Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400).grid()
The same as: Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400)
buttons.grid()?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run method grid() on a class, which is not a thing (classes are abstract, they cannot be referenced in code) from your error @DiogoDaniel

Comment: @DiogoDaniel That's because grid() call assigns `None` to `buttons` variable and then you're trying to call `columnconfigure(0)` on variable which contains `None`

Comment: oh no, it's not in a class @KatiaPunter

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 8):

As I said in the comment I hope this little code will let you understand the problem.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        pass

Joe = Person("Joe")
Joe.greet()

Pet = Person("Pet").greet()

print(Joe)
print(Pet)
```

The output:

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x7f1020983080>
None
```

The problem you have is that `Frame` constructor returns an object of type `Frame` while `grid` method does not return anything. That's why you have the `NoneType` error.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400).grid()
```

1. creates a `Frame` object,
2. calls `.grid()` on it,
3. bind the result of the call to `.grid()` to the name `buttons`
4. discards the `Frame` object

while this:

```
buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400)
buttons.grid()
```

1. creates a `Frame()` object and binds it to the name `button`
2. calls `.grid()` on the `Frame()` object and discards the result of this call.

So those two snippets are obviously not equivalent. In the first one, `buttons` is whatever `Frame().grid()` returned (seems that it's `None` actually), in the second, `buttons` is a `Frame()` object.

If you want to decompose your first statement, you need an intermediate variable (not `buttons`) to reference the `Frame()` object and call `grid()` on this variable:

```
frame = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400)
buttons = frame.grid()
```

Comment: Yes I got it! Thansk a lot

Answer (score 1):

it is the same!, you can do that too!

```
buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400).grid().columnconfigure(0)
```

you can use multi methods per a line

Comment: buttons = Frame(calculator, bg="green", width=200, height=400).grid().columnconfigure(0)

Error:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columnconfigure'

Comment: I dont know why did I upvote this... Sorry, but it is wrong, it does the same that your first snippet does, calling `columnconfigure()` in whatever `grid()` returns which happens to be `None`.